# SQL adding 2 query's to make one

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the data I'm working with in my SQL database:

```
Symbol | Close_Below
  AAPL       1        
  TSLA       0                
  AAPl       0
  AAPL       1        
  SPY        0                
  TSLA       1      
  SPY        0                
  AAPL       1
```

SQL Query I'm using to count how many times a symbol is in the database:

```
SELECT Symbol, count(*) as SymbolCount FROM data GROUP BY Symbol;
```

Output:

```
Symbol | SymbolCount 
  AAPL       4        
  TSLA       2                
  SPY        2
```

Another SQL Query I'm using to sum all the 1's for each symbol:

```
SELECT  Symbol, SUM(Close_Below) as Close_Below_Sum FROM data GROUP BY Symbol;
```

Output:

```
Symbol | Close_Below_Sum 
  AAPL        3        
  TSLA        1                
  SPY         0
```

**How would you go about getting the query to show the percentage of how many 1's to the symbol count for each symbol?** Example below.

Desired Output:

```
Symbol | Perc
  AAPL    0.75        
  TSLA    0.50                
  SPY     0.00
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as `AVG(Close_Below)`?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. I'm not trying to get the average. @Barmar

Comment: If they're all just 1 and 0, the percentage of 1's is the same as the average value. Try it.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFVfrgy1AoNeCBe3dpP8yh/0

Comment: Just tried it and it's correct @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SYMBOL, AVG(Close_Below) AS PERC FROM DATA GROUP BY SYMBOL;
```

Output:

```
SYMBOL  PERC
AAPL    0.75
SPY     0.00
TSLA    0.50
```